# How to set includes to be relative to the relativity of the source file from the root path?

Tags: c++, gcc, include, header-files, include-path

Sorry if my phrasing of the question is a bit confusing:

**How do I set includes to be relative to the relativity of the source file from the root path?**

I am trying to compile a C++ project (not my own), and there are two folders: `src` and `include`.

The `.cpp` source files are located in `src` and the header files are located in `include`.

I would like to compile all the source files.

However, the `#include`s in the source files are relative, as if the include folder tree and the src folder tree were merged.

For example `src/foo/bar/baz.cpp` might have `#include "baz.h"`. In this scenario, the header file is supposed to be searched for in `include/foo/bar/baz.h` rather than `include/baz.h`.

How do I achieve this with GCC? I'm sure a similar question exists on the internet already, I just can't figure out how to phrase my question well.

Here is what I've tried so far which is incorrect:

```
gcc src/**/*.cpp -I include
```

*Note: I still need to be able to append additional `-I <folder>` at the end of the command for including files the normal way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic compiler option to do what you want.

Solution 1: Change the #include directives to be relative to the include directory.

Solution 2: Don't use separate directories and move the headers into src directory.